# How to change the value of a config item in the controller? - Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, controller, config

I have a config file: `application/config/breadcrumbs.php`

Within the file I have the following configuration item:

```
$config['hide_number'] = TRUE;
```

How can I change the value of this config item through the controller.

I need to change the value of this config item one time only. How is this done???

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
$this->config->load('breadcrumbs');
$this->config->set_item('hide_number', 'your value');
```

See the docs for more info:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html

Comment: I am trying to do the same. But the changes are not saved in the config file

Comment: @AshishGaikwad this is not for permanent change this is use for that particular function only if you define in constructor  the it's use for that particular class only.