# Set session timeout based on the user role in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

There is a configuration setting in Codeigniter for setting session expiration:

```
$config['sess_expiration'] = 14400; //in seconds
```

But this applies for all types of user roles (admin/frontend users). I would like to set a lifetime session for an admin and just want to apply above setting for frontend users.

How could I achieve that?

Comment: [set config variable](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html?highlight=config%20class#CI_Config::set_item) like `if (user==admin){ $this->config->set_item('sess_expiration',30*24*2600)}`

Answer (score 1):

Session data get stored at server and it get destroy if browser will get closed. For lifetime login you need to make use of cookie 
Ex. "Remember me option"

If you want to implement with session you need to do it manually: Ex.

```
if ($ROLE != 'admin' && isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 1800)) {
    // last request was more than 30 minutes ago
    session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time 
    session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
}
$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); // update last activity time stamp
```

I have given example of core php you can implement it in codeigniter with

`$this->session->userdata('LAST_ACTIVITY');`

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->load->helper('cookie');
$cookie = $this->input->cookie('ci_session'); 
$this->input->set_cookie('ci_session', $cookie, '31557600');
```

Although I'm not sure its a good idea to make a session never expire, you could probably set the session cookie to expire one year in the future if the user is logged in as a admin.

Comment: I want to use session only. Also we can make admin session to 30 days as well which is also a huge amount of time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993795/how-to-change-the-value-of-a-config-item-in-the-controller-codeigniter